# Finding a collection of elements in a sorted array using Binary Search?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search-tree, binary-search

This is the challenge I am trying to solve:

> #### Input:
>
> The first line contains one integer n such that 1 <= n <= 10^5.
> The second line contains an array of n natural numbers, each not exceeding 10^9. The array is sorted in ascending order.
> The third line contains one integer k such that 1 <= k <= 10^5.
> The fourth line contains an array of k natural numbers, each not exceeding 10^9.
>
> #### Output:
>
> For each number from the second array, output the index of this number in the first array. If some number is not presented in the first array, output -1.
>
> In this problem, the array indexing is assumed to be started from 1.
>
> #### Sample Input 1:
>
> ```
> 5
> 1 5 8 12 13
> 5
> 8 1 23 1 11
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output 1:
>
> ```
> 3 1 -1 1 -1
> ```

### My attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arrtoSearch = new int[sc.nextInt()];
        for(int i = 0;i < arrtoSearch.length;i++){
            arrtoSearch[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int[] arr = new int[sc.nextInt()];
        for(int j = 0;j < arr.length;j++){
            arr[j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];
        for(int k = 0;k < arr.length;k++){
            System.out.println("arr[k]"+arr[k]);
            newArr[k] = Arrays.binarySearch(arrtoSearch, arr[k]);
        }
        for(int k = 0;k < arr.length;k++){
             System.out.println(newArr[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

### The problem

Instead of the expected output, I got:

```
2
0
-6
0
-4
```

How can I make it return -1 for when there is no match?

Comment: Now can you help me?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on the [`binarySearch` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte%5B%5D,%20byte)):

> **Returns:** index of the search key, if it is contained in the array within the specified range; otherwise, `(-(insertion point) - 1)`.

The method does not necessarily return -1 when there is no match: it could be another negative number, as you can also see when you run your code. You only know that a negative number indicates there was no match.

Secondly, you did not deal with the following specification in the task:

> the array indexing is assumed to be started from 1.

So, change the following:

```
        newArr[k] = Arrays.binarySearch(arrtoSearch, arr[k]);
```

with this:

```
        int res = Arrays.binarySearch(arrtoSearch, arr[k]);
        newArr[k] = res < 0 ? -1 : res + 1;
```